# Ubuntu pip is broken

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Ubuntu 4.4.0-176-generic

when I run pip or pip3 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 70, in <module>
    ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'
```

Many of the solutions indicate that I need to install a different version of requests, however, I cannot do that because I can't use pip.

Comment: pip3 works only with python3, which you aren't using.  You can also download the pip2 wheel for requests to install.  Also note, you're limited to versions <= 2.27.1 as >=2.28 versions have dropped support for python 2.7

Comment: Yes, pip in Ubuntu 16.04 was broken, in multiple ways. Time to upgrade.

Comment: `/usr/local/` suggest you have installed this Pip yourself. Which means it's hard(er) to say that Ubuntu-pip is broken.

Comment: "4.4.0-176-generic" is not an Ubuntu version, but a Linux kernel version. What Ubuntu version are you using (someone suggests 16.04, but please confirm or correct that)?

Answer (score -2):

When facing this problem, I removed `pip` using

```
apt remove python3-pip
```

and installed it again and it fixed my problem.

Comment: APT isn't uninstalling from /usr/local/.